# Install SQL Server 2012 with .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012, .net-framework-version

I have a strange problem trying to install SQL Server 2012.

I had a fresh copy of Windows Server 2008 R2. I installed Visual Studio 2012 on it, so the .Net Framework 4.5 installed on my Windows.

When I want to install SQL Server 2012 I get this error:

[image]

But there already is .Net Framework 4.5 installed:

[image]

How I can get rid of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx):

> When you install version 3.5, you get the 2.0 and 3.0 layers automatically, and apps that were built for versions 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 can all run on version 3.5. However, the .NET Framework 4 ends this layering approach, so apps built for 2.0. 3.0, or 3.5 will not work on version 4 or later.

Admittedly, MS's docs are confusing - in the very same article it's stated "You do not have to install previous versions of the .NET Framework or the CLR before you install the latest version."  I believe this statement is simply referring to the *install order*, however; 3.5 (+ 3.5.1) can be installed after 4.0 or 4.5 are on the system.